# SecurityException in Samsung Android 7,8, and 9 devices

Tags: android, kotlin, samsung-galaxy, android-securityexception

I am getting

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: broadcast from android asks to run as user -1 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL or android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

It is happening on **Samsung Galaxy devices  Android 7,8, and 9 devices** only.

Answer (score 0):

Add a check before reportFullyDrawn is called

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) 
 {
     activity.reportFullyDrawn() 
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**